# Give position to a dynamic box in css

Tags: html, css

I am writing a web page but

I have a problem to position `:after` of `.posts` to `bottom-right` in all boxes.

Example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu222/1/):

```
.posts::after {
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #DDD;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -41px;
    right: -2px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mu222/2/

Give `.posts` a position (relative), then set the `after` to `position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0`

Comment: My brain is now Regiment, and it was so easy, thank you ;)